# Displaying the result of a division in different cells

Tags: excel

I dont know if i asked my question correctly but

[This is what i want to do](https://gyazo.com/429e4c177c0d3a9722564deba5e8b0f5)

By filling the numbers in the yellow cells i want to display the numbers in green, the numbers in green are just a simple division of Quantity/Duration and the y start displaying at the column of "Start"

I know it can be easily done with visual basic, but i want to know if there is a way to do it without it.

Answer (score 0):

So three formulas, one array formula and two regular formulas:

column A:

```
=SUM(D2:K2)
```

Column B will refer to column C:

```
=MATCH(1E+99,D2:K2)-C2+1
```

Column C is an array formula:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(D2:K2<>0),0)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Once the three formulas are in the first row.  Copy/Drag them down.

[image]